# Using auditory feedback with Alexa?

Tags: user-behavior, feedback, audio-interface

I am working on an Alexa Skill, and we are conducting several interactions that may require some form of feedback while waiting or after a success.

I've not really seen any examples of whether or not to use auditory feedback with Alexa. Do users expect to hear dings and beeps? Ideally, I would like to utilize the ring color to indicate a success, but we're currently not able to do that.

Also, as a side note, does anyone know of a place to go for UX sound clips?

Comment: Typically, you can Google for some royalty free sounds. Otherwise, I do know that YouTube has open source stuff that you can use https://bit.ly/1wwplPp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voice feedbacks are the best way of communicating a message to the user but, at the same time sounds like dings & beeps are the fastest ways of communicating them.

The users in some cases don't have the patience to wait and hear the whole sentence. While people are much aware of the sounds that we use for errors and success we should try to utilize them more.

In my opinion, I would suggest combining both sound and voice feedback will be the best form of interacting with the user. For example,

**Me**: Alexa can you order one cold coffee from Starbucks

**Alexa**: Tadha(sound), I have placed the order successfully

I came across this website which has some beautiful sounds that you can check out. https://files.design/sounds

Answer (score 0):

Well like anything, your audience should dictate how you respond to them. If the change isn't obvious, then I always suggest **an acknowledgment and a completion state**.

Google Assistant almost always provides a confirmation (using the default code from Google) Alexa is much less frequent.

That said, VUI rarely uses beeps or dings when you interact with it. Instead, confirmations are always verbal.

So in your case, something like

> "Sounds great, I'm _______ but it will take a few minutes, I'll notify
>   you when I'm done."

Would be appropriate at least assuming that you can keep the skill active for that long.